# Android menu not inflating resource XML file using support v7

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar

The ActionBar does not change, I don't know why:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.testing_menu, menu);

        return true;
    }
}
```

I have included Android support library v7.

The **testing_menu.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/go_back"
        android:icon="@drawable/back"
        android:title="Go back"
        />
</menu>
```

[image]

The "Go Back" does not showing up.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.testing_menu, menu);

    return true;
}
```

why don't you call `return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);` ?